# Tikz - Draw Neural Network MLP diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, neuralnetwork

I am a beginner to TikZ. I want to reproduce 2 below diagrams. I was reading many tutorials and blogs about TikZ and was trying to implement but I still can not generate something like this 2 images. Can any one help me to reproduce this 2 diagrams? Thank you so much.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please remember that SE isn't a free service site. Your question will be better received if you show some effort (and some code) that people can copy-paste to test and modify. Thank you.

Comment: Most of what you need is in chapters 2 and 3 of the Tikz Manual (https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) so you should read that, and then come back with questions you have with your code that you’ve tried to use.